# When I click a button, the corresponding answer show appear and the other answers should not be displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have ten of these buttons and answers with the only difference between each one being the answer:

Example:

```
  <div class="showhim"> 
        <button class="answerbtn" onclick="revealAnswersFunction()">Click/Tap To Reveal Answers:</button>
    <div class="showme" style="display:none">1D, 2C</div>
</div>

  <div class="showhim"> 
        <button class="answerbtn" onclick="revealAnswersFunction()">Click/Tap To Reveal Answers:</button>
    <div class="showme" style="display:none">1A, 2D</div>
</div>

  <div class="showhim"> 
        <button class="answerbtn" onclick="revealAnswersFunction()">Click/Tap To Reveal Answers:</button>
    <div class="showme" style="display:none">1B, 2B</div>
</div>
```

Now what I want is that if the user clicks a button, the relevant answer will be revealed. Currently, it is doing this but there is a catch, it displays all answers which is not what I want. I want it so that dependent on which button I click, it only reveals the answer for that one and the other answers are not displayed.

How can the code be manipulated to incorporate what I am guessing is some soft of loop to retrieve the button that has been clicked and display the corresponding answer and hide all the other answers?

```
var answers = document.getElementsByClassName("showme");
  var revealAnswers = document.getElementsByClassName("answerbtn");

function revealAnswersFunction() {

  if (answers.style.display === "none") {
    answers.style.display = "inline-block";
  } else {
    answers.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function revealAnswersFunction(e) {

var all =document.getElementsByClassName('showme');
for(let i=0;i<all.length;i++){
   all[i].style.display='none';
   }

var div = e.nextSibling.nextElementSibling;
div.style.display = "inline-block";

  
}
```

```html
<div class="showhim"> 
        <button class="answerbtn" onclick="revealAnswersFunction(this)">Click/Tap To Reveal Answers:</button>
    <div class="showme" style="display:none">1D, 2C</div>
</div>

  <div class="showhim"> 
        <button class="answerbtn" onclick="revealAnswersFunction(this)">Click/Tap To Reveal Answers:</button>
    <div class="showme" style="display:none">1A, 2D</div>
</div>

  <div class="showhim"> 
        <button class="answerbtn" onclick="revealAnswersFunction(this)">Click/Tap To Reveal Answers:</button>
    <div class="showme" style="display:none">1B, 2B</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

a simple solution would be to use the index in the function:

```
<div class="showhim"> 
        <button class="answerbtn" onclick="revealAnswersFunction(0)">Click/Tap To Reveal Answers:</button>
    <div class="showme" style="display:none">1D, 2C</div>
</div>

  <div class="showhim"> 
        <button class="answerbtn" onclick="revealAnswersFunction(1)">Click/Tap To Reveal Answers:</button>
    <div class="showme" style="display:none">1A, 2D</div>
</div>

  <div class="showhim"> 
        <button class="answerbtn" onclick="revealAnswersFunction(2)">Click/Tap To Reveal Answers:</button>
    <div class="showme" style="display:none">1B, 2B</div>
</div>
```

```
function revealAnswersFunction(index) {

  if (answers[index].style.display === "none") {
    answers[index].style.display = "inline-block";
  } else {
    answers[index].style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

in the HTML, I added an index number to `onclick="revealAnswersFunction(0)"`
. Then used that index in the function for the answer you want to display.

For future reference when you call `document.getElementsByClassName()` it returns an array, so you will need the index of the array item you want to modify.

A much cleaner solution would be to use [Event Listeners](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp) to add an `onclick` event to the buttons in the javascript.

Answer (score 1):

First hide the all answers using **hide()** method and then change the display properties of the current answer.

```js
function revealAnswersFunction(e) {
  $('.showme').hide();
  e.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = 'inline-block';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="showhim"> 
 <button class="answerbtn" onclick="revealAnswersFunction(event)">Click/Tap To Reveal Answers:</button>
  <div class="showme" style="display:none">1D, 2C</div>
</div>
    
<div class="showhim"> 
 <button class="answerbtn" onclick="revealAnswersFunction(event)">Click/Tap To Reveal Answers:</button>
 <div class="showme" style="display:none">1A, 2D</div>
</div>
    
 <div class="showhim"> 
 <button class="answerbtn" onclick="revealAnswersFunction(event)">Click/Tap To Reveal Answers:</button>
  <div class="showme" style="display:none">1B, 2B</div>
 </div>
```